# How to disable copy/paste of specific control(for e.g. Tab key) on input fields?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to disable copy/paste of specific control on HTML input field ? I found way to disable c/p with **preventDefault()**, but i need to disable c/p of specific control ?

EDIT:

Or how to restrict specific key to enter on input field? (e.g. TAB key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable copy paste in HTML input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805803/disable-copy-paste-in-html-input-fields)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable pasting text into HTML form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form)

Comment: On input change you can remove disallowed input just by replacing them with nothing something like `in = in.replace('\t', '')` where `in` is the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your Html code

```
<input type="text" value="" id="myInput" />
```

Your js code.

```
  window.onload = function() {
                        var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
                     myInput.onpaste = function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I just want to disable TAB key