# How to enable copy and paste in search bar only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below script to stop copy, paste, f12, ctr+u etc and disable mouse right click.

```
    <script> var message=&quot;Copyright 2017-2018&quot;;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; e.shiftKey &amp;&amp; e.which==73)
    return false;

  if (e.which == 123)
    return false;

  if (e.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; ((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 65) || (e.which == 88) || (e.which == 67) || (e.which == 2) || (e.which == 3) || (e.which == 123) || (e.which == 83))) {
    alert(message);
    return false;
  }
}

// right click code
var isNS = (navigator.appName == &quot;Netscape&quot;) ? 1 : 0;
if (navigator.appName == &quot;Netscape&quot;)
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN || Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler() {
  return false;
}

function mousehandler(e) {
  var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
  var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
  if ((eventbutton == 2) || (eventbutton == 3)) return false;
}

document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;

//select content code disable  alok goyal
function killCopy(e) {
  return false
}

function reEnable() {
  return true
}

document.onselectstart = new Function(&quot;return false&quot;)
if (window.sidebar) {
  document.onmousedown = killCopy
  document.onclick = reEnable
}
    </script>
```

I want to enable only copy and paste feature on my search bar. Below is my search bar code.

```
<div class="search-input">
<input aria-label="Search this blog" autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="हिंदी में ही लिखें" value="">
</div>
```

Is there is any way to only enable copy and paste feature on the search bar.

Comment: Any code that attempts to prevent right-clicking and keyboard commands can easily be overcome. This is a futile effort and a bad idea from a UI design perspective.

Comment: You know that F12 has also a menu item...you can check focused control (by class or input type) but PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE don't do it. I HATE when copy & paste is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, disabling copy-paste is a bad idea, as it will make users confused. Does my clipboard still work? Or is this site *broken*? Besides, it could be activated through the Developer Tools anyway.

However, if you still want to continue:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input:not(#search)"))
 .forEach(function(object){object.onpaste = function(e) {e.preventDefault();}})
}
```

```html
<input id="search" placeholder="Search">

<input>
<input>
<input>
```

Based upon [Disable copy paste in HTML input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805803/disable-copy-paste-in-html-input-fields)

Comment: `.querySelectorAll().forEach()` is not supported in all browsers and so the resulting node list should be converted to an `Array` for compatibility with `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll()).forEach()`.

Comment: It's work only in desktop. But in mobile, I am not able to paste in the search bar.

Comment: Enhanced solution after the comment of @ScottMarcus