# disable text selection while right click with js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent

i have a custom context menu for canvas, but with Text elements i have a problem, when i try to click on text element by right-click i have text selection (like double click).

When i use try to use:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

its couldn't help, because i have text selection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not really "answer-worthy", but due to my low reputation, I cannot write a comment. So, that being said, you have events like "onCopy", "onCut", "onPaste", etc. You can disable each and every one of them individually. You can see an example of that here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Copy, cut and paste disabled</h2>
    <input type="text" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" autocomplete=off/>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you have any further questions - **[here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-disable-text-selection-copy-cut-paste-and-right-click-on-a-web-page.html)** is the full article.

Comment: thx, i saw this article, but i need when i have right-click event on selected element, maybe i can't explain with my bad english, for example on site canva.com, u add text element on workspace, and try to click right click and word in text not selecting

Comment: You have seen this **[article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805803/disable-copy-paste-in-html-input-fields)**. I think that might do. However, this is something very easy to bypass and you cannot really restrict that kind of behavior persistently imo.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes inline javascript expression is a good trick.Forexample form tags we are writing

`<form id="test" onsubmit="return false;">`

So I based on this example. maybe you can try this

`<canvas oncontextmenu="return false;"></canvas>`

edit after comments : which button actication you need excalty I dont know, but maybe you can try to find 1,2,3,4...

```
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
   // forexample right-click is equal to two
    if (e.button == 2) {
      // Block right-click menu, thru preventing default action
      e.preventDefault();
    // if its not work with e.preventDefault(); add next line return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: sry, but its not in my case

Comment: okey ,then. can you also try this `document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); return false;
})`

Comment: i try to explain a problem, when i do u example, first click by right click its good, but second click i have selecting text, but i dont need it, i need selecting text just by double click

Comment: I edited my solution, can you try it please ?

Comment: its dosen't work, maybe its help for example, go to https://www.canva.com/design/play?category=tACFal755_E&locale=en-GB&analyticsCorrelationId=61bbd3d0-9b61-47ea-8ae9-a7c5e68c00db
add text from the left tab

Comment: maybe it would be a solution for you , https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321596/11842307

Comment: e.button == 2 its for double click (

Comment: visit last link which I shared. you will find a lot of solution in there. maybe u need just css code like `user-select: none` ı dont know. again visit last link. maybe u need mouse.eventDetail>1 Idk, or e.button == 2 for duble click or u try e.button == 0 for one click. or maybe u need to listen mouseDown event .. share ur last state with me pls if u find a solution pls edit the post.